# Try to use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() in Raspberry Pi

Tags: asp.net-core, raspberry-pi, .net-core

I have a asp.net core 2.1 project that will create and execute a process in PI. Project is running fine, but it throw exception:"**System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (8): Exec format error**" when try to start process.
I had try publish -r ubuntu.16.04-arm, but still not working.
Is netcore 2.1 support to create process in ARM yet?

Comment: I found the cause, because I try execute a .out file that not build for ARM, that why it throw exception "Exec format error"